# preventing Textarea input after pixel width is reached

Tags: javascript, textarea, pixel, preventdefault

I am building a Tool where you can preview how Google will display your result.
When the user inputs more than 920 pixels of characters the result should cut it off and add on "...".

I can't do this using max-length because every letter and font comes with differents widths. 
In javascript I am making the output equal to the input, then I created a second output which has no line break. If I would use the first output the innerWidth wouldn't return the pixel width of the string but of the whole block. The second output is invisable as its just for measuring purposes.

I tried using the preventDefault method when the innerWidth is = or > than 920px. But it hasn't been working for me.
Using a text-overflow property on the output div can't be used here because I wan't the containers width to be dynamic and not a width of 460px * 2 rows or 306px * 3 rows etc...

what would be the corrent if-function to use here and how do I prevent further input?

Thank you for your help.

Side note: Ignore the poorly writte CSS I've quickly copied it from my document which I can't show.

```js
 function snippet()
{
  //copies input to output
var metaIn = document.getElementById('metaIn');
  var metaOut = document.getElementById('metaOut');
  metaOut.value = metaIn.value;

  //copies input to counting space
  var metaOutPix = document.getElementById('metaOutPix');
  metaOutPix.value = metaIn.value;

  //pixel countdown
  document.getElementById('metaOutPix').innerHTML = document.getElementById('metaIn').value
  var span1 = $( "span#metaOutPix" );
  $( "#metaCountPixel" ).text(span1.innerWidth() + "px / 920px");

  //character countdown
  var metaNum = metaIn.value
  var metaCount = metaNum.length;
  document.getElementById("metaCount").innerHTML = metaCount + " Char";

  //stop input by pixel ??
  
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway");
html, body {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  margin: 3px;
  max-width: 80em;
  overflow-x: hidden; }

h1 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center; }

.input-wrap {
  width: 100%; }
  .input-wrap h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    background: #254e61;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: .2em;}
  .input-wrap textarea {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    resize: none;
    border: solid 2px #254e61;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial; }
  .input-wrap #metaIn {
    height: 8em; }

#preview {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 2px #5badff;
  margin-top: 1.5em; }
  #preview h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #5badff;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: .4em; }

.outputs {
  padding: 4px; }

#metaOut {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden; }

#metaOut, #metaOutPix {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #545454;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#metaOut{
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100px;
}

.countspace{
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.countdown {
  color: white;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 18px; }

#metaCount{
  text-align: center;
}
#metaCountPixel{
  text-align: right;
}



@media (min-width: 750px) {
  body, html {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto; } }
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .inputs {
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    grid-template-areas: ". tworow" ". tworow"; }

  .input-wrap:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: tworow; }
    .input-wrap:nth-child(3) #metaIn {
      height: 192px !important; }

  .input-wrap textarea {
    margin: 0 0 0 0; }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inputs">
    <div class="input-wrap" id="meta-div">
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <div class="countdown" id="metaCount">0 Char</div>
        <div class="countdown" id="metaCountPixel">0px / 920px</div>
        <textarea type="text" name="metaIn" id="metaIn" onkeyup="snippet()" onkeypress="snippet()" maxlength="320" onkeyup="displayTextWidth()"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="preview">
        <h3>Snippet Preview</h3>
        <div class="outputs">
            <textarea type="text" name="metaOut" id="metaOut" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos ipsum voluptatem nemo reiciendis asperiores accusamus suscipit aliquid eveniet quo vero." readonly></textarea>
            <span class="countspace" id="metaOutPix"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this in my snippet below?

I used add a `keydown` listener in the `textarea` when it reaches 920px or more, in this listener I set that only `Backspace` and `Delete` keys will be allowed, any other key will be ignored with the return false.

(For tests only I limited to 50px instead of 920)

```js
var ellipsisAdded = false
function snippet(){
  var metaIn = document.getElementById('metaIn');
  var metaOut = document.getElementById('metaOut');
  metaOut.value = metaIn.value;

  var metaOutPix = document.getElementById('metaOutPix');
  metaOutPix.value = metaIn.value;

  document.getElementById('metaOutPix').innerHTML = document.getElementById('metaIn').value
  var span1 = $( "span#metaOutPix" );
  $( "#metaCountPixel" ).text(span1.innerWidth() + "px / 50px");

  var metaNum = metaIn.value
  var metaCount = metaNum.length;
  document.getElementById("metaCount").innerHTML = metaCount + " Char";

  if (span1.innerWidth() >= 50){
    let txtArea = $("#metaIn")
    txtArea.on("keydown", (ev) => {
        console.clear()
        if (ev.key != "Backspace" && ev.key != "Delete"){
          console.log("max Pixels reached!");
          if (!ellipsisAdded){
            ellipsisAdded = true
            let currentText = txtArea.val()
            let newTxt = currentText.substring(0, currentText.length - 1) + "..."
            txtArea.val(newTxt)
          }
          return false
        }
      })      
  }else{
    $("#metaIn").off("keydown")
    ellipsisAdded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway");
html, body {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  margin: 3px;
  max-width: 80em;
  overflow-x: hidden; }

h1 {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center; }

.input-wrap {
  width: 100%; }
  .input-wrap h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    background: #254e61;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: .2em;}
  .input-wrap textarea {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    resize: none;
    border: solid 2px #254e61;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial; }
  .input-wrap #metaIn {
    height: 8em; }

#preview {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 2px #5badff;
  margin-top: 1.5em; }
  #preview h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #5badff;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: .4em; }

.outputs {
  padding: 4px; }

#metaOut {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden; }

#metaOut, #metaOutPix {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #545454;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#metaOut{
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100px;
}

.countspace{
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.countdown {
  color: white;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 18px; }

#metaCount{
  text-align: center;
}
#metaCountPixel{
  text-align: right;
}



@media (min-width: 750px) {
  body, html {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto; } }
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .inputs {
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    grid-template-areas: ". tworow" ". tworow"; }

  .input-wrap:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: tworow; }
    .input-wrap:nth-child(3) #metaIn {
      height: 192px !important; }

  .input-wrap textarea {
    margin: 0 0 0 0; }

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<div class="inputs">
<div class="input-wrap" id="meta-div">
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <div class="countdown" id="metaCount">0 Char</div>
    <div class="countdown" id="metaCountPixel">0px / 50px</div>
    <textarea type="text" name="metaIn" id="metaIn" onkeyup="snippet()" onkeypress="snippet()" maxlength="320" onkeyup="displayTextWidth()"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div id="preview">
    <h3>Snippet Preview</h3>
    <div class="outputs">
        <textarea type="text" name="metaOut" id="metaOut" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos ipsum voluptatem nemo reiciendis asperiores accusamus suscipit aliquid eveniet quo vero." readonly></textarea>
        <span class="countspace" id="metaOutPix"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Added the feature you talk about in comments, replacing last character by `"..."`.
But take care that the three dots will occupy some pixels, more than a single character

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: could you also tell me how I would replace the last three characters with "...".

Comment: you can set the `innerText` of the textarea with the same text but removing the last character and adding the `"..."`, I'll edit my answer to add this feature

Comment: once again thank you. I have one more things to add: this method does not work after pasting in a string that exceeds the 920px limit. you can keep typing on forever then. Would you help me fix this problem?

Comment: it's important that when you are making many questions you see if it's not going out of the scope of the main question you made, if yes, then create a new question here in S.O. In this case, I think it's better to make a new one, because now you'll need another kind of listener, for when user paste something. Create a new question, you'll get more visibility to get answers that can help, I'm out of time to help now.